# Don't repeat return values in C#8 switch syntax

Tags: c#, switch-statement, c#-8.0

Suppose I have the following in classic C#:

```
public string Size(byte b)
    {
        switch (b)
        {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                return "small";
            default:
                return "big";
        }
    }
```

The C#8 developers correctly recognized that there is a lot of cruft in the syntax. So in C#8, I can write it more compactly like this:

```
    public string SizeCs8(byte b)
        => b switch
        {
            0 => "small",
            1 => "small",
            _ => "big",
        };
```

Definitely an improvement. But one thing bothers me. I have to repeat the value "small". Previously I didn't. I'm wondering if it is possible to do it the C#8 way without repeating the value "small"?

Comment: If hte code in place of big is complex. just use a Function for it. For strings, you propably should be using constatns anyway.

Comment: The 1st one is not valid C#. There is no fallthrough and there has to be 1 break per case,

Comment: @Christopher It’s not a fall through, multiple values are allowed to exist for the exact same case block

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen My bad, I mixed that up. However the IL that SharpLab makes for it is interesting: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ+WRiqQLIAUAlLfY/3wYBfQaVElyOAAykAygEsAXjA7AAngBcYpYF1F0C/fgGcA7vI1gAFqVV7DRhgceOwAQ2PapIUS9LvPUhwfBz9HDAB2UgAiYwBbNwAbROiAbl8XABMYADM3AFdEjRCwl0iY4HkAczSM4VERAiEgA

Comment: FWIW, C# 9 is likely to allow `b switch { 0 or 1 => "small", _ => "big" }`

Comment: "Definitely an improvement" - very arguable

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code for that, by adding a `when` clause

```cs
public string SizeCs8(byte b)
            => b switch
            {
                var x when x == 0 || x == 1 => "small",
                _ =>"big",
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the first (longer) version to be preferrable. Compact code is nice, but not if it compiles to more bytes.

But why not toss the `switch` statement? This is more compact:

```
public string SizeCs8(byte b) => (b <= 1) ? "small" : "big";
```

Comment: It's a toy example. That won't be possible in general.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch: It would be possible in many cases. All I can go by is what you posted.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch Funny enough, the if syntax is what Case 1 will compile into on the IL side. However the short syntax is kept as swtich, despite the obvious overlap. | But as it turns out both the when clause and pattern matching has you covered.